# Simple counter with setInterval() not working?

Tags: javascript, counter, setinterval

I would like to make a simple counter with setInterval(), like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
  if(typeof i === 'undefined') {
    let i = 1;
  } else {
    i++;
  }
  console.log(i);
}, 1000);
```

What  this does is it crashes saying how `i is not defined` and I would like to understand why?

Does it fail cause `console.log(i)` is not in the same scope as where `let  i = 1` is?
So in JavaScript every `{ }` block has its own scope?
I know I could define `i = 1` without `if else`, but would like to learn why does this example fail to work? Is it cause of scope?

Also, I would like this to work with defining a variable, only if it does not exist, something like `isset()` in PHP!

Comment: i is local variable within if context, error is correct, you need to declare it before if

Comment: `let` and `const` are scoped inside if/else blocks, too.

Comment: In your line 2, you are asking for `typeof i`, but `i` never existed before that. The fix would be to add another line above the `if(` line: `let i;`

Comment: To make the counter work, you need `i` to be global, declared outside the setInterval, or declared inside *without* var or let or const.